# A Day Trip to New York City

Tags: new-york-city

So, let's say I want to go to New York City to see a Broadway show and head back home immediately after. Say I live relatively equidistant from both Baltimore, MD and Washington DC, and BWI isn't too far either (for example, in Columbia, MD or Elkridge, MD). If I have access to a car, and am perfectly willing to walk some distance, take metro/train, or a bus (but no planes, you know how crazy those prices can be). What would the most feasible option for making the trip to and fro without breaking the bank?

Comment: I'm not sure how anyone can answer this without knowing your actual starting point (at least down to the level of a particular city or town). We have no idea how close you are to a metro, train, or bus stop.

Comment: Both Elkridge and Columbia are thoroughly covered by the Howard County bus system. If it helps I do indeed live within walking range of a bus stop.

Comment: Amtrak, absolutely, because the train stops at Penn Station, just 9 little-blocks from where all the Broadway theaters are, certainly less than a mile.  When I do a daytrip, I usually *walk* it.  If you're near BWI, you're near BWI Amtrak.

Comment: Evening show or matinee?  You will have a lot fewer options at 11pm or later after the evening shows let out.  Also, weekday or weekend?